# Get results from text box then continue actionResult

Tags: html, asp.net

So I am trying to make a form on a asp.net website where a user loads a page in this case called Software once this page loads it checks if two variables are empty and if so it returns the Software View which then allows a user to fill in information for those said variables.  The problem is when the user puts in the information the submit button doesn't actually submit the changes.  If it did then the IF statement should no longer be valid and would be ignored so the page would be redirected to the PostSoftware page.  My assumption is I might need some sort of javascript check for when submit button is clicked to do something but I am unsure.

**Software Frontend:**

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:#D1D3D4;">
    <img src="/Images/TECH_BARlogoBLACK.png" style="width:1000px;height:200px;" class="animate__heartBeat">
    <p class="lead" span style="background-color: #FFFF00;">Software Request</p>
    <br>
    <p class="text-left"><b>Enter Computer Name:</b></p>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.computerName, new { id = "computerName", name = "computerName"}) 
     <p style="font-size: 14px; text-align: left;"><b>To obtain your Computer Name: </b>Click Start (bottom left windows icon) and type in System Information, On the 5th line, your Computer Name is listed as the System Name <br></p>
    <p class="text-left" style="width: 1000px;"><b>Business Justification:</b> <br> @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.businessJustification, new { id = "businessJustification", name = "businessJustification", @cols = 40, @rows = 3,@style="width: 1000px;"}) </p>
    <label for="Software">Select the Software(s) you need!</label>
    <br>

<!-- NOTICE FROM HERE DOWN -->
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => @Model.selectedSoftwareList, new MultiSelectList(Model.softwareList, "Text", @Model.selectedSoftwareList),
                                                    new
                                                    {
                                                        id = "_SelectedSoftwareList",
                                                        @class = "form-control multiselect-dropdown",
                                                        multiple = "true",
                                                        style = "width:200px;height:300px;",
                                                        data_placeholder = "Select Software"
                                                    })
    <br>
    <br><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg" style="font-size: 20px">Submit</button>
    

</div>
```

**Controller**

````
        public ActionResult Software(TicketModel model)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Request software through the Tech Bar.";
            
            var snow = new clsServNowAuth();
            var tbl = clsServNowAuth.SoftwareTable();
            var tbl2 = clsServNowAuth.SoftwareTableID();
            tbl.Wait();
            tbl2.Wait();
            model.softwareList = tbl.Result;
            model.softwareListID = tbl2.Result;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.computerName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.businessJustification))
            {
                // TODO
                return View(model);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("PostSoftware", model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostSoftware(TicketModel model)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.computerName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.businessJustification))
            {
                // TODO
                return View(model);
            }
            // get user info from AD currently ZID and Email
            List<string> lstUserInfo = clsADInterface.GetInfo(model);

            var test = model.selectedSoftwareList;
            // submit software request
            clsServNowAuth.SoftwareRequest(lstUserInfo, model.computerName, model.businessJustification, model.softwareList, model.softwareListID);
            return View(model);
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the form creation for the submit button

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
        { }
```